# React Lingui - translate input placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation

I have a problem with translation `placeholder` prop for input. I have a wrapper component `<Text />` which renders `<input>` one. I've tried to translate placholder this way:

```js
import { Trans, t } from '@lingui/macro'

const passwordPlaceholder = t('password.placeholder')`Enter password`

// this doesn't works
<Text as='input' type='password' name='password' placeholder={t(passwordPlaceholder)} required />

// neither
<Text as='input' type='password' name='password' placeholder={<Trans id={passwordPlaceholder} />} />

// not
<Text as='input' type='password' name='password' placeholder={passwordPlaceholder} />
```

I tried a lot of time to solve this problem, no solution found...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was suggested by my former colleague, using render function with object parameter contains 'translation' property. I hope this answer helps someone.

```js
    <Trans id={passwordPlaceholder} render={({translation}) => (
     <Text as='input' type='password' name='password' placeholder={translation} required />)} 
/>
```